# How to draw histograms in r

Tags: r

My code is reading in a file which looks like this:

```html
Wafer Analyses 
%HN20396815 150.000000 03/27/2016 04:06:27
Vf2 Site
2.76 1
2.32 2
2.56 3
2.45 2
2.76 4
2.98 3
2.58 1
2.42 2
2.76 1
2.32 4
2.56 3
2.45 2
2.76 4
2.98 3
2.58 1
2.42 2
```

then I segregate "Vf2" data by "Site" and plot for each site in a histogram, however the histogram doesn't get printed out, how do I rectify this? This is my code>

```html
blufile <- read.table("C:/blufiles/WFRHN20396815_700.blu", skip = 2, header = TRUE, sep="\t")
Vf2 = blufile["Vf2"]
Site = blufile["Site"]
blufile2 <- data.frame(Vf2, Site)
blufile2$Vf2[blufile2$Site == '2']

set.seed(42)
p1 <- blufile2$Vf2[blufile2$Site == '1']                     # centered at 4
p2 <- blufile2$Vf2[blufile2$Site == '2']                     # centered at 6
p3 <- blufile2$Vf2[blufile2$Site == '3']                     # centered at 4
p4 <- blufile2$Vf2[blufile2$Site == '4']                     # centered at 6

plot( p1, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/4), xlim=c(0,4))  # first histogram
plot( p2, col=rgb(1,0,0,1/4), xlim=c(0,4), add=T)  # second
plot( p3, col=rgb(0,1,0,1/4), xlim=c(0,4), add=T)  # first histogram
plot( p4, col=rgb(1,1,0,1/4), xlim=c(0,4), add=T)  # second
```

I want a similar output -> [image]

Comment: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(blufile, aes(x = Vf2)) + geom_histogram(bins = 5) + facet_wrap(~Site)`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

The solution @alistaire have provided worked with the data you have provided.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Vf2)) + 
     geom_histogram(bins=5) + 
     facet_wrap(~Site)
```

[image]

The data df used in this case is:

```
structure(list(Vf2 = c(2.76, 2.32, 2.56, 2.45, 2.76, 2.98, 2.58, 
2.42, 2.76, 2.32, 2.56, 2.45, 2.76, 2.98, 2.58, 2.42), Site = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("Vf2", 
"Site"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Please elaborate more on your issues if this still do not work.

EDIT:

The issue with your code is that you used `plot` which would result in a x,y point plot, instead of `hist`.

Here's a solution with base:

```
df_list <- split(df, df$Site) #produce a list of 4 data.frame, each with one level of Site

dev.off() # close existing output on console
for(i in 1:length(df_list)){ 
   dat <- df_list[[i]]$Vf2 # select Vf2 data from site i
   hist_col <- c(rgb(0,0,1,1/4), rgb(1,0,0,1/4), rgb(0,1,0,1/4), rgb(1,1,0,1/4))[i] # select rgb colour for site i plot
   hist(dat, col=hist_col, xlim=c(0,4), ylim=c(0, 5)) #plot histogram for each site
   par(new=T) # add new histogram layer on top
```

}

[image]

The solution for `ggplot` is slightly more confusing in this case:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Vf2, fill=factor(Site), colour=factor(Site))) +
     geom_histogram(data=df %>% filter(Site==1), bins=5, alpha=.5) + 
     geom_histogram(data=df %>% filter(Site==2), bins=5, alpha=.5) +
     geom_histogram(data=df %>% filter(Site==3), bins=5, alpha=.5) + 
     geom_histogram(data=df %>% filter(Site==4), bins=5, alpha=.5) +
     theme_bw()
```

[image]